# Android Notification: at your request android is blocking this app's notifications

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, activity-recognition

I'm developing an android application with Java, Node.Js as backend and Postgres as database. The application for now has an authentication and I have implemented the recognition of user activity through the related API. My problem however, is that the notifications of the application result turned off and blocked in the device settings.
I've tried both on different emulators and on my real device but there is no way to turn on the app notifications that are blocked.

[blocked notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COlpx.png)

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MTS"
        >
        <service
            android:name=".ARServices.ActivityRecognitionService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".ARServices.ActivityRecognitionBackgroundService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MTS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MTS">
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".ARServices.ActivityRecognitionService"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How can I solve this problem? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What android version are you using? Notification permission is required since API level 33.

Comment: Of course there's no way to override a block from device settings-  the user has explicitly said they don't want to receive notifications from you.  You don't get to force them.  Your job is to convince the user that you're valuable enough to be worth enabling notifications for.

Comment: @Pisoj i'm using the android API 33 Tiramisu

Comment: @GabeSechan the app is not in production and I don't want to force anyone to give permission, maybe you don't understand. I want to implement a permanent notification but it's impossible for me to test it if notifications are blocked on the emulator too.

Comment: GO the emulator settings and unblock it.  It is acceptable to pop up alert window asking the user to enable notifications when they run your app, and have that link directly to settings.  But there's no way to automatically enable it.  And you wouldn't want to for testing, as you'd be testing a non-realistic scenario.

Comment: You **need to declare the permission** in your manifest, but you don't heed to handle permission requesting it if you are testing (in production you really should), just go to settings and allow notification permission.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding [`POST_NOTIFICATION`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission) permission to your manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

and then going to the **settings** and allowing notification permission.

That's good for experimenting, but as soon as you decide to go in production, you should handle permission requesting. [This](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bHlLYhSrXvc) is a good video.

Comment: thank you for the solution and for your kindness! Problem solved, my fault.